# How to configure Jersey to run on servlet 3.0 environment (Jetty)?

Tags: jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0, jetty-9

I am configuring Jersey 2.25.1 to run on Jetty 9.4.4 server without an Application subclass. Jetty supports Servlet API 3.1 so I configure my application for this environment exactly as [the documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3.pluggability.noapp) said, thus my web.xml is

```
<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Servlet declaration can be omitted in which case
         it would be automatically added by Jersey -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and pom.xml besides other contains the following Jersey related dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm-all-repackaged</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After I deploy my war and start the server I get `javax.servlet.UnavailableException: No class in holder javax.ws.rs.core.Application` exception. Here is full stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: No class in holder javax.ws.rs.core.Application@83f91b4==null,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
```

Can anyone help me to fix the configuration?

Comment: Can you explain how are you running this application?

Comment: I put a war file built with maven to the webapps directory of a Jetty servlet container.